# How to update my Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two computers, one laptop and one PC. My laptop was the first to get the Anniversary update. I successfully installed WSL and get it working. Only a few bugs like `inotify` or my main one `socket hang up` randomly popping up when trying to do test units in node.js on local server... Later I updated my tower to anniversary and set up WSL. This one still had the `inotify` issue, but no more `socket hang up`. So I guess a new update fixed it. I tried removing WSL on my laptop using `lxrun /uninstall /full` and the reinstall, but still same issue. Windows is up to date. How can I update my WSL system on laptop?

Comment: WSL can now be updated to the 16.04 Ubuntu release provided you upgrade to 1703.  I have flagged this question as a duplicate with the apppriate answer.  An existing WSL instance, created before 1703, must be upgraded manually to 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following to make sure the installed packages are up to date.

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: Add a `sudo apt upgrade` to install the updates as well.

Comment: Both does nothing. Upgrade only update python